# “Everyone else's life” vs “... else's lives”

Tags: grammatical-number

It would seem as though this is incorrect, since we each only have one life.

Is my intuition correct that it should be everyone else's **life** and not everyone else's **lives**?

Answer (score 11):

*Everyone else's life* would be correct. In this case *everyone* is a singular pronoun. [(See this explanation of *everyone* being singular.)](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/indefinite-pronouns.aspx) *Else* is just a determiner used after *everyone*.

Allow me a digression that I think you might find helpful when thinking about whether to use *life* or *lives* in similar sorts of construction. The most memorable explanation of whether to use a plural or singular word that I've ever encountered comes from the book *Words Into Type* (p. 357). Under the heading and subheadings of **Nouns, Number, Singular with a plural possessive** there is this clear explanation:

> To avoid ambiguity a singular noun is often used with a plural possessive **when only one of the things possessed could belong to each individual**.
>
> - *Manufacturing helps many people in the smaller cities to earn their living.*
> - *Forbes knew most of them by their first name.*
> - *Some of them could not pay their rent.*
> - *They eyed each other furtively and cursed beneath their breath.*
>
> Similarly:
>
> - *Think of the last name of five pupils in the room.*
> - *The steam line ruptured, causing the death of seven longshoremen.*
> - *They doubled their efforts to discover the identity of two men who struck a man with their automobile and then fled.*
>
> Care must be taken not to apply the rule to the wrong noun.
>
> **Wrong:** *It is pretty clear that the smile on the face of the delegates, whenever they look at each other, is not a sincere one.*
>
> **Right:** *...on the faces of the delegates ...* [ *Smile* is the noun the rule applies to.]

Comment: +1 A concise exposition, with authority, of a position I avoid in my own usage!

Comment: Unless all the delegates had one face.

Comment: @Noah; so *...on the faces of the delegates* would clearly mean that, being politicians, they were all two-faced. :)